# How to search for a string in a line, then delete to end of line from there

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I have a requirement which I am sure I can do in vi (plenty of other solutions I am sure), and this is it.

I have a file that looks like this

> 1234   Some Text HERE rest of line
>   1235   Some Other Text HERE rest of line

What I want to do is delete text from, and including the word HERE to the end of the line, leaving me with this;

> 1234   Some Text
>   1235   Some Other Text

I have done search and replace things in vi, but am not sure how to do a search then run a command.

Any help, as always is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: "I have done search and replace things in vi": Well, delete is a corner case of replace (with nothing, that is), isn't it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, in `vi` there are many ways to skin this particular cat. As has already been stated, a simple solution to exactly this problem is:

```
:%s/HERE.*//
```

However, to answer your more general question:

> I have done search and replace things in vi, but am not sure how to do a search then run a command.

you want the `:g[lobal]` command:

> `:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]`
>
> ```
>         Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
>         lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
> ```

This would actually be more long-winded for your exact example, but for tasks such as deleting lines that match a specific pattern, it is considerably more concise.

e.g. if you wanted to instead delete all lines that contain `HERE`, you would run:

```
:g/HERE/d
```

Factoid: this command form is the origin of `grep`'s name: `g/re/p`, shorthand for `global/{regex}/print`.

Answer (score 8):

How about that:

```
:%s/HERE.*//
```

This pattern replaces the part of the line starting with `HERE` and replaces it with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> will delete from the cursor to the end of the current line. So if you're searching using the `/` command, it'll be...:

```
/HERE<enter>d$
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using sed also:

```
sed "s/HERE.*//"
```

Example:

```
echo "this is a test HERE test" | sed "s/HERE.*//"
```

Result:

```
this is a test
```